# Как для group by добавить вывод поля

Tags: sql

[image: Схема БД]

Задание формулируется так:

Для отделов с номером, не большим 50, выведите должности, занимаемые их сотрудниками.
В каждой строке выведите номер отдела, должность (job_id), максимальную и минимальную зарплату сотрудников отдела в этой должности.
В выборку включайте только те строки, где минимальная зарплата по должности больше 5000.
Результат отсортируйте по максимальной зарплате в порядке возрастания. Указание: используйте только таблицу employees

Как в мой запрос добавить вывод номера департамента(department_id)?

```
SELECT job_id, MAX(salary), MIN(salary)
FROM employees
WHERE department_id >= 50
GROUP BY job_id
HAVING MIN(salary) > 5000
ORDER BY 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте решить через подзапрос:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.job_id, e.department_id FROM employees as e
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT job_id, MAX(salary) as max, MIN(salary) as min
  FROM employees
  WHERE department_id >= 50
  GROUP BY job_id
  HAVING MIN(salary) > 5000) as e2 
ON e.job_id = e2.job_id
ORDER BY e2.max
```